# How to reduce coupling when waiting for client message

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, server, client-server

I'm currently designing a server-client game and would like to lower the amount of tightly-coupled dependencies within the game. Basically, I would like the client to change its state when receives a message from the server. The pseudocode would look something like this:

```
    switch(inputThread.getMessage()){
    case "dead":
        die();
        break;
    case "heal":
        heal();
        break;
    }
```

The problem is that changing what gets sent on the server state requires me to also change the client state, which could be problematic if I want to send a large variety of messages. What design pattern could I use to decouple the client and server?

Comment: Between a client and a server, you need some coupling. I would, however, get rid of the `switch` statement and replace it by e.g a [chain of responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)

Comment: consider making all of the messages enums (perhaps with one or 2 parameters). that way you only have one file to change and you can detect omissions when you fall through a switch to default. both client and server need to understand the messages so it's hard to decouple.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of [Command Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). This way each operation can get encapsulated in a concrete command object and sent to the server-side.
The command instance can contain needed parameters and get executed on the server side.